# Do you have to store the value returned by conditional operator in java

Tags: java, operators, conditional-statements

I have a method , where I am doing a conditional operation.
But I get a compilation error.

```
public void hello(){
    int x=15;
        x==15 ?"Hi":"Bye";
}
```

If I edit the line and put something mentioned below , the error goes away:

```
String salutation=x==15 ?"Hi":"Bye;
```

My question is --is it mandatory to assign the value being returned by a conditional operator to a variable?

Comment: You have asked an answer.

Comment: The reasoin of an error in line `x==15 ?"Hi":"Bye;` is that you're assigning String to int

Comment: x==15 is the condition. Where am I assigning string to an int?

Answer (score 2):

`x==15 ? "Hi" : "Bye;` just floating around does nothing; it's a pure expression. It's like just writing `"Hi"` in the middle of your code. You need to assign it to a variable for it to actually effect anything.

So yes, it's mandatory in the sense that if you want the ternary to do something, you must assign the result; providing no part of ternary (the condition, and both of the clauses) carries out side effects.

Answer (score 0):

> Do you have to store the value returned by conditional operator in
>   java

Not necessarily, but to simplify you cannot declare it without using it.

You may for example assign it to a variable as you did  :

```
String salutation=x==15 ?"Hi":"Bye;
```

But you are not forced to store the value in a local variable.
You have other ways to use it.

You may for example pass it as a parameter that waits for a String :

```
myMethod(x==15 ?"Hi":"Bye");

public void myMethod(String string) {... }
```

Or you can still use it to apply a method on :

```
if ((x==15 ?"Hi":"Bye").equals("Bye")){
    ...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You are getting an error because you are not assigning the value based on the condition. Assigning a single variable to one of two states based on a single condition is such a common use of `if-else` that a shortcut has been devised for it, the conditional operator, `?:`. you can't use the shorthand form `?:` if the condition doesn't return any value. Your example can be rewritten

```
public void hello(){
    int x = 15;
    String salutation;
    if (x == 15){
      salutation = "Hi";
    }else 
     salutation = "Bye;
}
```

Using the conditional operator we can rewrite the above example in a single line like this:

```
public void hello(){
    int x = 15;
    String salutation = x==15 ?"Hi":"Bye;
}
```